# Add constraints programmatically when hiding a UIView using Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I'm trying to add some constraints to a `UIView` called `contentContainer` in a XIB. I'm green to Auto Layout, but new iPhones have forced me into it. Apologies, but I don't have 10 reputation, so stack won't let me post a picture of the XIB so this will be more complicated to explain...

Within the `contentContainer` is a `UIView` called `fixedContentContainer`. That container is the same every time in terms of height of all the `UIViews` inside it. I've added constraints to the contents of that container in IB. Everything is working fine there. Below the `fixedContentContainer` also in `contentContainer` are 4 `UIView` objects:

1. A static `UILabel` called `friendsLabel`
2. A `UITableView` called `tableView`
3. A static `UILabel` called `eventDescriptionHeaderLabel`
4. A dynamic `UILabel` called `eventDescriptionLabel`

What I'm trying to accomplish is simple. If a user opens an event and they don't have friends going, I hide `friendsLabel` and `tableView` then move `eventDescriptionHeaderLabel` and `eventDescriptionLabel` up to fill the empty space. For now though, I just want to start simple. I'm just trying to add constraints programmatically to `friendsLabel` that I can add in IB no problem, so I'm clearly doing something wrong. (I'd be happy to upload the rest of the code once I get everything working).

Here's where I try to add the constraints programmatically:

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"fixedContentContainer":self.fixedContentContainer,
                                  @"friendsLabel":self.friendsLabel,
                                  @"tableView":self.tableView,
                                  @"eventDescriptionHeaderLabel":self.eventDescriptionHeaderLabel,
                                  @"eventDescriptionLabel":self.eventDescriptionLabel};

// Add 8px of space between bottom of fixedContentContainer and top of friendsLabel
[self.contentContainer addConstraints:

        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[fixedContentContainer]-8-[friendsLabel]"
                                                options:0
                                                metrics:nil
                                                  views:viewsDictionary]];

// Add 15px to the left and 10px to the right of padding between friendsLabel and superview (contentContainer)
[self.contentContainer addConstraints:

        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-15-[friendsLabel]-10-|"
                                                options:0
                                                metrics:nil
                                                  views:viewsDictionary]];
// Set height for friendsLabel at 21px
[self.contentContainer addConstraints:

        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[friendsLabel(21)]"
                                                options:0
                                                metrics:nil
                                                  views:viewsDictionary]];
```

Just as a side note, would you add a height constraint directly to a `UILabel` or still to the `containerView`? Here's what I'm getting from the console (I don't get anything if I add the exact some constraints through IB):

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)



"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x84cafae0 EBWebImageView:0x84cafa40.width == 1.78448*EBWebImageView:0x84cafa40.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x84cb04a0 V:[UILabel:0x84cb03a0'Kimberly Otte | Jenna Lau...'(26)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x84cb0c50 V:[UIImageView:0x84cb0ba0(20)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x84cb0f40 V:[UIImageView:0x84cb0e20(20)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x84cb16b0 V:[UILabel:0x84cb1540'Event Details'(21)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x84cb19a0 V:[UITableView:0x7c361e00(225)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x84cb2fc0 H:[EBWebImageView:0x84cafa40]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x84caf9a0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x84cb2ff0 H:|-(0)-[EBWebImageView:0x84cafa40]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x84caf9a0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x84cb3020 V:|-(0)-[EBWebImageView:0x84cafa40]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x84caf9a0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x84cb30e0 V:[EBWebImageView:0x84cafa40]-(0)-[UILabel:0x84cb03a0'Kimberly Otte | Jenna Lau...']>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x84cb3170 V:[UILabel:0x84cb03a0'Kimberly Otte | Jenna Lau...']-(8)-[UIImageView:0x84cb0ba0]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x84cb3260 V:[UIImageView:0x84cb0ba0]-(8)-[UIImageView:0x84cb0e20]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x84cb33b0 V:[UIImageView:0x84cb0e20]-(8)-[UILabel:0x84cb1540'Event Details']>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x84cb34a0 V:[UILabel:0x84cb1540'Event Details']-(5)-[UITableView:0x7c361e00]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x84cb34d0 V:[UITableView:0x7c361e00]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x84caf9a0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x84cb54e0 H:[UIView:0x84caf9a0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x84caf900 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x84cb5510 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x84caf9a0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x84caf900 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x84cb5540 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x84caf9a0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x84caf900 )>",
"<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x84cb55a0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(581)-[UILabel:0x84cb37e0'Friends']   (Names: '|':UIView:0x84caf900 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x84cb6c20 V:[UIView:0x84caf9a0]-(8)-[UILabel:0x84cb37e0'Friends']>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc3cb90 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIScrollView:0x860ed080(320)]>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7d237f80 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0x84caf900.width == UIScrollView:0x860ed080.width>"


Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x84cb19a0 V:[UITableView:0x7c361e00(225)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Please let me know if anything else is needed and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. The `NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraints` were auto-generated by IB because I didn't set them in IB. I just added all the constraints to the XIB in IB, checked the "Remove at Build Time" box for the ones I wanted to change and everything was smooth sailing from there. I'm starting to like Auto Layout as the solution ended up being short, elegant and a lot cleaner than messing with frames.